# Set page title by child action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC4 I allow controllers to set the current page title by setting ViewBag.PageTitle.
But

Part 1. It doesn't work when ViewBag.PageTitle is set in a ChildAction (_Layout.cshtml doesn't see it); How can I set the page title from a ChildAction?

Part 2. How can I set the page title in a cached ChildAction, as the action doesn't get called anymore when it's cached?

Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Product(long productId)
{
    ViewBag.PageTitle="test";   //Works
    return View(productId);
}

[OutputCache(Duration=300)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ProductPartial(long productId)
{
    Product product=AProductProvider.Instance.GetProduct(productId);
    ViewBag.PageTitle=product.Name; //Doesn't work

    return View(product);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext` to retrieve information about parent view:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ProductPartial(long productId)
{
    Product product = AProductProvider.Instance.GetProduct(productId);
    ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewBag.PageTitle = product.Name;

    return View(product);
}
```

**UPDATE:** For this to work, in your parent view you have to call ViewData like:

```
@ViewContext.ViewData["PageTitle"]
```

Reason is a bit obscure. Child **action** receives proper reference to parent action's ViewData (same instance of object), but every **view** (ViewPage) receives *copy* of ViewData in the state original ViewData has during view initialization in `Sytem.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper` method. ViewData of parent pages is initialized/copied before call to child action occurs, so later updates in child actions do not apply. This is source code of MVC that does that:

```
// ....
ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData)
{
    Model = metadata.Model,
    ModelMetadata = metadata,
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
    {
        FormattedModelValue = formattedModelValue,
        HtmlFieldPrefix = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName),
        VisitedObjects = new HashSet<object>(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects), // DDB #224750
    }
};
```

However, `ViewContext` keeps references, not copies to Controller context data, so you can use that one. On the other side, if you use `ViewContext.ViewData`, you have to be aware of execution order of views, child actions, sections, layouts...

Comment: I wished it would work! Unfortunately it doesn't, ViewBag.PageTitle stays empty for the layout. It doesn't work in the other way either, when I set ViewBag.PageTitle="test"; in the action I can't retrieve that value in the ChildAction.

Comment: I might have something wrong because now the value set by the parent action is correctly available to the child; however: it's still null at the _Layout level and there is still a caching problem :/ (I can't cache the entire page because I've user specific information displayed, but I'll look to ASP.NET MVC Donut Caching if it can solve my issue)

Comment: For caching part, I would try to compose/split actions and views differently. Even setting title from child view doesn't feel right to me somehow. This looks to me like main part of the page, specially if it determines title of the page.

Comment: Understand your point. The Partial view in my use case IS actually the main part of the page but it requires a bunch of SQL queries + computation. Setting it in the cache would allow me to bypass all that queries, while leaving the global page untouched (because it contains user related info). Donut caching would definitively solve this issue in a way better fashion, and I will orient myself in this direction to solve my issue. Thanks again for your help!